# customizing switch using Material-UI with React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/6yn3q2nnwn

I am trying to use the iOS styled switch just like the one in the link above.

In my component that uses a switch, I pretty much copied the codes used in that sandbox.

Below are the codes in my component.

```
const styles = theme => ({

  iOSSwitchBase: {
    '&$iOSChecked': {
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
      '& + $iOSBar': {
        backgroundColor: '#52d869',
      },
    },
    transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    }),
  },
  iOSChecked: {
    transform: 'translateX(15px)',
    '& + $iOSBar': {
      opacity: 1,
      border: 'none',
    },
  },
  iOSBar: {
    borderRadius: 13,
    width: 42,
    height: 26,
    marginTop: -13,
    marginLeft: -21,
    border: 'solid 1px',
    borderColor: theme.palette.grey[400],
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[50],
    opacity: 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color', 'border']),
  },
  iOSIcon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
  iOSIconChecked: {
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
  },
});
```

and in my render

```
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const dateDisplay = moment(this.props.createdAt).format('MMM YYYY');
    //alert(this.props.rowItems.status)
    if (this.state.show) {
      return (
        <tr
          className="experiment-list__row"
          onMouseDown={() => this.props.onRowHovered(this.props.rowItems.id)}
        >
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.name}</td>
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.owner}</td>
          <td>{dateDisplay}</td>
          <td className="experiment-list--col__switch">


            <Switch
              classes={{
                switchBase: classes.iOSSwitchBase,
                bar: classes.iOSBar,
                icon: classes.iOSIcon,
                iconChecked: classes.iOSIconChecked,
                checked: classes.iOSChecked,
              }}
              disableRipple
              onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
              checked={this.props.rowItems.status}
              onChange={this.change}
            />

          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This gives me an error saying that `classes` is `undefined`.

Why is it not working?

**edit**

This is the thing that I actually export to another component

```
const List = props => {
  return (
    <table className="experiment-list">
      <tbody>
        <ListHeader />
        {props.rowItems.map((data, i) => (
          <ListRow
            key={i}
            rowItems={data}
            onRowHovered={props.onRowHovered}
            toggleSwitch={props.toggleSwitch}
            shouldShowItem={props.shouldShowItem}
            viewActive={props.viewActive}
          />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: This has to do with not integrating material ui correctly. And even maybe an older style. MUI just released v1 with good docs and examples. 
https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/
When I just need to use a component quickly I copy and paste the entire component into it's own 'switch.js' and use it where I need. Make sure to follow the setup and usage correctly!

Comment: This is the exact page that I referred to, but it doesn't' work. Any help?

Comment: Are you using @next? npm install material-ui@next? Your code snippet doesn't look like you're using the example I provided. The specific error you are getting is that the Switch comp doesnt have a prop named classes because it's probably not actually using the material ui switch

Comment: that's the exact same page. And I put `const { classes } = this.props;` in the first line of render

Comment: @Dawn17 Can you share the full code of the component where the Switch is imported?

Comment: Adding that line does nothing if there is no such classes prop being actually passed down. I would suggest you create a brand new switch comp and copy paste the material ui example and just test it. Where are you importing Switch? Can you not link us your entire code?